# How to Format Decimal Place for Numbers in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have  jquery code like this

```
 $('#myTable tbody:eq(1)').append('<tr class='+marker.id+'><td>'+ marker.title +'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lat()+'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lng()+'</td></tr>');
    });
```

which exports number like:

> 11.064874980506636

Can you please let me know how I can make it shorter like(or round it)

> 11.0648749

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toFixed()`.

```
(11.064874980506636).toFixed(7);
```

So you can do:

```
marker.position.lng().toFixed(7);
```

since that function is returning a float.

Answer (score 0):

Use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)...

```
11.064874980506636.toFixed(7)
```